# Бот не отвечает в беседе, а в лс группы отвечает vk Api php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

У меня есть бот, этот бот на версии vk api 5.131, написан на php. Вчера бот в беседах работал, проснулся и он больше не работает. Помогите, в чем может быть ошибка? В лс работает бот, администратора выдал везде. Ошибки не выдаёт.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня бот, не реагирует на сообщения в беседе, а в лс группы реагирует, в беседе есть админка.